# What is the difference between these two statements in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

this part is a SKShapeNode

```
var rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)) 

self.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, nil)
```

AND

```
let rect = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
```

They seems to be acting differently in the simulator and I'm wondering if these are different in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The origin, (0, 0) point, of a `SKShapeNode` is the center of the node and its path is drawn relative to that point. Therefore, a shape node created with the following `CGRect`

```
CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
```

will be drawn with its bottom-left corner in the center of the shape node.

The convenience method `SKShapeNode(rectOfSize...)` centers the rect in the shape node by offsetting the `origin` argument of the `CGRect` by half of the rectangle's width and height. In this case, the rect's `origin` is (-15, -15).

You can create a `CGRect` that is centered in an `SKShapeNode` by offsetting its origin:

```
let height = CGFloat(30)
let width = CGFloat(30)
let anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)

CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -width*anchorPoint.x, y: -height*anchorPoint.y), size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
```

where `anchorPoint` defines the relative "point in the sprite that corresponds to the node’s position."

You can also use `SKShapeNode(path:path, centered:true)` which will center the path using its bounding box.